# ViewFlipper não detecta MotionEvent após inserir ScrollView nele

Tags: java, android

Uso *ViewFlipper* com 4 "páginas". Funcionava, até eu inserir *ScrollView* em cada uma das páginas. Como posso resolver?

Comment: Com a informação que você disponibilizou a única solução que me ocorre é: não use o *ScrollView* :)

Comment: Não edite o título com "RESOLVIDO", aceita a sua reposta como sendo a correta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver com o componente ViewPager, ao invés do ViewFlipper :)
Usei o exemplo presente na documentação da plataforma: http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/animation/screen-slide.html#pagetransformer